# How to check if element is displayed on website?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to create a login test so the 1st step is that if the user successfuly logs in the script should look for an element in the home page post login.

My problem is that if the user unable to login python throws a `NoSuchElementException` exception and does not go to else.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def login_test(self):
    driver_location = 'D:\\chromedriver.exe'
    os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = driver_location
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_location)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    driver.get("http://www.example.com/")

prof_icon= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,'button')]")
if prof_icon.is_displayed():
    print("Success: logged in!")
else:
    print("Failure: Unable to login!")
```

I have also tried:

```
 prof_icon= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,'button')]")
 try:   
      if prof_icon.is_displayed():
        print("Success: logged in!")
 except NoSuchElementException :
        print("Failure: Unable to login")
```

But the script always crashes and throws exception. I just need it to print the message in else incase the element is not displayed.

Comment: Could you share the code above prof_icon= 
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,'button')]") and html fot it ?

Comment: I have added the code above prof_icon. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. To locate the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  try:   
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.button")))
      print("Success: logged in!")
  except TimeoutException:
      print("Failure: Unable to login")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  try:   
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class,'button')]")))
      print("Success: logged in!")
  except TimeoutException:
      print("Failure: Unable to login")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
except NoSuchElementException:  #correct name of exception
    print("Failure: Unable to login")
```

You can see if element exist and if not print "Failure: Unable to login".
Note the plural "s" in `.find_elements_*`.

```
prof_icon = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,'button')]")
if len(prof_icon) > 0
    print("Success: logged in!")
else:
    print("Failure: Unable to login")
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Actually I wrote it 'NoSuchElementException' in my code still the same issue

Comment: A edited my answer, let me know if the solution works